# How can I have the full range in the x- and y-axis labels in a plot?

Tags: r, plot, label, axis-labels

I have two variables, `x` and `y`

```
x = runif(8, 0, runif(1, 1, 5))
y = x^2
```

that I want to plot. Note that the range of `x` (and hence `y=x^2`) is not always the same.

So, the command

```
plot(x, y, pch=19, col='red')
```

produces

[image]

However, I don't want the borders around the graph, so I use the `bty='n'` parameter for plot:

```
plot(x, y, pch=19, col='red', bty='n')
```

which produces

[image]

This is a bit unfortunate, imho, since I'd like the y-axis to go all the way up to 4 and the x-axis all the way to 2.

So, I ue the `xaxp` and `yaxp` parameters in the `plot` command:

```
plot(x, y, pch=19, col='red', bty='n', 
     xaxp=c(
       floor  (min(x)),
       ceiling(max(x)),
       5
    ),
    yaxp=c(
       floor  (min(y)),
       ceiling(max(y)),
       5
    )
)
```

which produces [image]

This is a bit better, but it still doesn't show the full range. Also, I thought it nice that the default axis labaling uses steps that were like `1,2,3,4` or `0.5,1,1.5,2`, not just some arbitrary fractions.

I guess R has some parameter or mechanism to plot the full range in the axis in a "humanly" fashion (0.5,1,1.5 ...) but I didn't find it. So, what could I try?

Comment: You can include `axes=FALSE'` in the initial call to `plot()` and then use `axis()` to build custom axes with the ticks and labels where you like using 'at', e.g., at=seq(0, 2, 0.5) for your axis.

Comment: As a side note: Always set a seed before generating random numbers (e.g. `set.seed(1)`) so others can fully reproduce your output.

Comment: @lukeA thanks, I will try to improve in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
plot(x, y, pch=19, col='red', bty='n', xlim=c(min(x),max(x)),
  ylim=c(min(y),max(y)), axes=FALSE)
axis(1, at=seq(floor(min(x)), ceiling(max(x)), 0.5))
axis(2, at=seq(floor(min(y)), ceiling(max(y)), 0.5))
```

Or if you'd prefer to hard-code those axis ranges:

```
axis(1, at=seq(0, 2, 0.5))
axis(2, at=seq(0, 4, 0.5))
```

Is that what you were after?

Comment: `axis(1, at=seq(floor(min(x)), ceiling(max(x)), 0.5))` and
`axis(2, at=seq(floor(min(y)), ceiling(max(y)), 0.5))` seems to even be a bit nicer

Comment: Ah, right, I will edit the answer to incorporate that.